# Slowing down speed of SeekBar's thumb

Tags: android

I've got this Activity:

[image]

Here you can see a SeekBar with TextView above. SeekBar contains 24 hours in minutes, and TextView shows the exact time. My boss said that it's too hard to "catch" exact minute on this SeekBar, because minutes changing really fast. So i need to make it more convenient.

I think it will be OK if i just slow down speed of SeekBar's thumb, so it won't react on finger moving with 1/1 speed. But i don't know how to do it and i need your advise)

Does anyone faced similar problem? Maybe there are some other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to set steps to increment

```
int step = 1;
int max = 120;
int min = 90;
int maxset = (max - min) / step;

    seekBar.setMax(maxset);
    seekBar.setProgress(maxset / 2);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            float value = (float) ((min + (progress * step)) / 100.0);
            tv_seekval.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```